# Can i use react-native flex similiar to bootstrap row/column system?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Is this good idea to use flex in react native like this?creating your own components which retrive flex values?I were using bootstrap grid system before and now im trying to learn react native.

Is there any way to show this example using react-native bootstrap on the stack?

```js
let FlexContainer = ({direction,children}) =>{
  console.log(direction)
  var style = {
  
    flexDirection:direction || 'row',
    display:'flex',
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%'
  
  }
  return(<div style={style}>{children}</div>)

}

let FlexBox = ({val, color, children}) => {

  return (
    <div style={{backgroundColor:color, flex:val}}>{children}</div>
  )

}




class LayoutExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  
  render(){
  
    return(
    <div className='screen'>
      <FlexContainer>
        <FlexBox val={1} />
        <FlexBox color="blue" val={1} />
        <FlexBox color="red" val={1} />
      </FlexContainer>
    </div>
    )
    
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<LayoutExample />,document.getElementById('example'))
```

```css
.screen {

  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid black;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Is this approach valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

It is valid, though in my opinion it's better to separate style considerations from logic as much as possible.

I used to work with bootstrap as well, but since I moved to react native I didn't use any grid system and I didn't feel like I missed something, each screen I style according to what I need from that screen, and of curse trying to reuse components as much as possible.